# How to obtain the stacking order of all elements in a webpage?

Tags: html, css, browser

That is, how can I obtain a complete, total ordering of all the elements according to their rendered, stacking order programmatically? I need this to determine whether any element is above/below the other element.

Note that merely checking if two elements geometrically overlap is not good enough. I truly need the stacking order (i.e. who is located above/below whom).

Comment: Maybe create selectors parsing DOM following specification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context